# Laravel: where to write session code before controller

Tags: laravel, session, controller, locale, lang

For a multilingual site a have in all method of all controller this line: \App::setLocale(session('lang'));

Where can I put it else to not repeat in each? (tried in AppServiceProvider, ...)

Or are there any other possibilities for multilingual sites?

Cheers,

Yves

Answer (score 0):

The best place to perform this kind of action might be a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

In the `handle` function of a custom middleware you have access to the session and thus you can change the locale. You can then apply this middleware to all applicable routes or even a middleware group.

Comment: Thank you, will try this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

By default laravel maintains locale in `config/app.php` file

You can simply override it by modifying the locale value dynamically. I would like to suggest you add the code on `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` on `boot` method.

You could achieve it in two ways

```
// Modifying config value
$this->app['config']['app.locale'] = session("lang", "en");
```

or

```
// Setting by App::setLocale
$this->app->setLocale(session("lang", "en"));
```

#### AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {   
        // Modifying config value
        $this->app['config']['app.locale'] = session("lang", "en");
        // or 
        // Setting by App::setLocale
        $this->app->setLocale(session("lang", "en"));
    }
}
```